# jQuery how to show the next div

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know how I can show the next div (.hide) when the Clickbox is clicked.

link to the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fvuqW/

this is my jQuery code:

```
        $(function(){
            $('.form input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
                {
                $(this).change(function()
                    {
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                        {
                        $(this).next('div.hide').css('display', 'block');
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                        $(this).next('div.hide').css('display', 'block');
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: Your if statement is completely useless here

Comment: why use `.css( 'display', 'block' )` if you have `.show()`

Comment: which is the next div here? the one with `hide`?

Comment: please, have a look on what `next()` really does : http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.hide` divider isn't anywhere near your input. You need to first find the containing divider of your input element, then call `.next()`. I've condensed your code down to just:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    $(this) /* The checkbox */
        .closest('div') /* The input's ancestor divider (".form_checkboxes"). */
        .next() /* The divider next to the ancestor divider. */
        .toggleClass('hide') /* Toggle the class "hide". */
    ;
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/fvuqW/3/).

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wjkEy/

I have made small changes in your provided JS code `display:none` in the else code, you could simply use `.show` or `.hide`.

This should fit your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parents('.checkbox').find('.hide').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $(this).parents('.checkbox').find('.hide').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').siblings("div").toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fvuqW/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
          $('.hide').toggle();
       });
    });
```

You can even add transitions to it. Like fadeIn or fadeOut or anything else with jQueryUI.

**More info** : **[jQuery UI - EFfects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$(this).closest('.hide').nextAll('.hide').eq(0).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.hide').toggle(this.checked)
    }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CKVYj/)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#checkbox').change(function() {
          if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             // do something...
       }
     else{
           //do something...
       }  

    });
});
```

Take a look at this demo
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/4/)